# Test to verify at a given time only one submenu can be opened

Tags: protractor

I am writing a protractor E2E test to verify only one submenu can be opened at once.

Below is the code that is to click a row to render a submenu.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="submenu" [resizeable]="false" [width]="60">
    <ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template></ng-template>
    <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
      <cust-submenu [row]="row"></cust-submenu>
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
```

I am attempting to write a test using protractor that if in a data-table there are 10 rows then clicking on a row-1 should open a submenu and clicking on row-2 should close the previous submenu and open submenu-2 and so on.

Appreciate any suggestions.

[UI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbqyA.png)

Comment: In this case I would prefer to have a visual picture of UI before me

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov , attached the UI

Comment: Suggestion #1 don't cover this in test automation - this seems to be more a unit test. 

However, if you still want to cover it check if submenu elements are present on the page but hidden, or they don't even exist in the source of the page. And let me know